# Why I can pass an array as input to a lambda function that uses numpy but I cant pass it to a lambda function without numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, lambda

Starting from these two lambda functions

```
import numpy as np

relu = (lambda x: np.maximum(0, x),
        lambda x: 1 if x > 0 else 0)
```

Obviously the two functions work correctly when I pass a single number, but when I pass an array/list relu[0] works but not relu[1].

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(relu[0](a))  # this one works
print(relu[1](a))  # not works
print([relu[1](v) for v in a])  # also works
```

Comment: Because `relu[0]` calls a numpy function which accepts vectors, but `relu[1]` is an ordinary Python expression which does not.

Comment: What's the error message? It'll make it pretty clear why this doesn't work.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are asking? You can *pass in* a numpy array just fine. What you cannot do is perform an operation on numpy arrays that does not make sense for numpy arrays (testing if it is larger than 0) – just as you cannot perform an operation on *any other value* for which the operation is ill-defined (e.g. testing whether a ``dict`` is larger than 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many numpy functions, e.g. [maximum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html), accept `array-like` arguments, i.e. types that can be converted to numpy arrays, and numpy coverts them to numpy arrays automatically.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(relu[0](a))  # a is converted from list to numpy array
```

Your second example raises a TypeError

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

because you can't compare a `list` and an `int`.
Compare the last two examples in the question:

```
print(relu[1](a))  # compare 'list' to 'int': Fail
print([relu[1](v) for v in a])  # compare 'int' to 'int': OK
```

Like what [Nils Werner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/636626/nils-werner) mentioned, if you are putting your functions inside the same container, it is a good practice to make sure they accept the same arguments, i.e. they have same interfaces.
However, as both of your functions in `relu` are doing the same thing, I suppose you are just making a example to demonstrate your doubts.

Comment: This is not a good solution, as the two functions still use a different interface: One accepts array-likes, the other one only accepts scalars. It is better to adjust the functions themselves.

Comment: @NilsWerner I agree what you said. However, I am trying to explain why some of the examples work while some don't. All codes are taken from the question. I will edit my answer to avoid such misunderstanding.

Comment: I think the question is "why" this does not work but not "how" to do this; therefore I am just stating the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can, if you make sure `x` is an array using `np.asarray()` an then use `np.where()`:

```
relu = (
    lambda x: np.maximum(0, np.asarray(x)),
    lambda x: np.where(np.asarray(x) > 0, 1, 0),
)
relu[0]([-1, 0, 1, 2])
# array([0, 0, 1, 2])
relu[1]([-1, 0, 1, 2])
# array([0, 0, 1, 1])
```